# How do I force my heroku django project to use https?

Tags: django, heroku

I have a django site hosted by Heroku (tachlisgeredt.com), but I am having a weird problem.
Basically, for anyone going to my site going to 'tachlisgeredt.com' doesn't work, only going to 'tachlis.herokuapp.com', and even that shows 'not secure'. However, going to 'https:/www.tachlisgeredt.com' works, and it shows 'secure'.
So basically, how do I force my django site hosted by Heroku to use https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Django section of this link: https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls

Basically, Heroku forces you to do this in your Django settings.py file.